# Show/hide entire box element in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyjs

I'm currently trying to find a way to hide/show an entire box() element (and everything inside) in R Shiny. I want to create a maybe a button which allows the user to expand a specifict box and then to hide it with the same (or even different) button. I do not want to use conditionalPanel, as my application is really big and it creates some problems.

A sample code can be found below:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(collapsibleTree)
require(colorspace)
# Dataset is from https://community.tableau.com/docs/DOC-1236
load(system.file("extdata/Superstore_Sales.rda", package = "collapsibleTree"))
# For the sake of speed, let's only plot sales in Ontario
Superstore_Sales <- Superstore_Sales[Superstore_Sales$Region=="Ontario",]

# Define UI for application that draws a collapsible tree
ui <- fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Collapsible Tree Example 3: Gradient Mapping"),

  # Sidebar with a select input for the root node
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(

      tags$a(href = "https://community.tableau.com/docs/DOC-1236", "Sample dataset from Tableau")
    ),

    # Show a tree diagram with the selected root node
    mainPanel(
      box(title="Tree Output",width='800px',
        collapsibleTreeOutput("plot", height = "500px")
      ),
      box(title="Input",
        selectInput(
          "hierarchy", "Tree hierarchy",
          choices = c(
            "Customer Segment", "Product Category", "Product Sub-Category",
            "Order Priority", "Product Container"
          ),
          selected = c("Customer Segment","Product Category", "Product Sub-Category"),
          multiple = TRUE
        ),
        selectInput(
          "fill", "Node color",
          choices = c("Order Quantity", "Sales", "Unit Price"),
          selected = "Sales"
        )


      )  
    )
  )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a collapsible tree diagram
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$plot <- renderCollapsibleTree({
    collapsibleTreeSummary(
      Superstore_Sales,
      hierarchy = input$hierarchy,
      root = input$fill,
      attribute = input$fill
    )
  })
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The main idea is to have a button(or buttons) that belong to each box and hide/show only that specific box. Maybe it's possible with shinyjs, but I can't seem to comprehend how it should work with my current structure.

Comment: It's the two boxes with the titles "Tree Output" and "Input". I want them to show up as hidden and to be expandable through a button.

Comment: I mean, which library are they from?

Comment: oh, shinydashboard is the library - forgot to add it to the code. I will edit it now

Comment: Why don't you just use the `collapsible` argument in `shinydashboard::box`?

Comment: I tried it, but it did not react when clicking it.

Comment: Probably because it needs to be used with `dashboardPage`, `dashboardHeader`, etc. Nevermind

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Here's a minimal example that you can extend into your actual application.

It uses `shinyjs` to show/hide the box. The key is to give the box an `id`, and then use that `id` value in the `show`/`hide` functions

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            useShinyjs()    ## IMPORTANT: so shiny knows to use the shinyjs library
        ),
        mainPanel(
            box(id = "myBox", title = "Tree Output", width = '800px',
                    selectInput(inputId = "myInput", label = "my input", choices = c(letters))
                    ),
            actionButton(inputId = "button", label = "show / hide")
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output){

    ## observe the button being pressed
    observeEvent(input$button, {
        
        if(input$button %% 2 == 1){
            shinyjs::hide(id = "myBox")
        }else{
            shinyjs::show(id = "myBox")
        }
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! Just implemented on one of the boxes in my original app and it worked fine!

Comment: `observe(` instead of `observeEvent(input$button, {` suffices

Answer (score 12):

Instead of checking if its divisible by 2 why not use `toggle` functionality within `shinyjs`

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      useShinyjs()
    ),
    mainPanel(
      box(id = "myBox", title = "Tree Output", width = '800px',
          selectInput(inputId = "myInput", label = "my input", choices = c(letters))
      ),
      actionButton(inputId = "button", label = "show / hide")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output){

  ## observe the button being pressed
  observeEvent(input$button, {
    shinyjs::toggle("myBox")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: it's just a coding habit I haven't grown out of yet

Comment: The answer given by @SymbolixAU is also useful for when you are dealing with input selection dropdowns instead of buttons. (For future readers).

Comment: The answer given by @SymbolixAU also allows to initiate in a hidden state when using `input$button %% 2 == 0` instead of `input$button %% 2 == 1`