# Hide section on condition

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, flexdashboard

I am building a flexdashboard in R shiny with several sections. Some sections should only be shown under certain conditions and stay hidden otherwise. In this example, I would like to hide the valuebox when its value is 0.

Expected result:

[image: value = 0][image: value > 0]

---

**EDIT I condensed the example:**

````
---
title: "Test"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    vertical_layout: scroll
runtime: shiny
---


### Valuebox {.value-box}

```{r}
library(flexdashboard)
library(shiny)
value <- reactiveValues(value = sample(c(0,1), 1))
renderValueBox({
      valueBox(value$value)
})
````

Any help or pointers are much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite straightforward to do if you add a JavaScript block. I cannot get your example code to render, so I'll use the [Old Faithful example](https://quarto.org/docs/interactive/shiny/) in the Quarto docs which plots a histogram based on an `sliderInput`.

If you wanted to hide the `plotOutput` (with id `"distPlot"`) when the `sliderInput` (with id `"bins"`) value is 1, add this code block to the Quarto document:

````
```{js}
$(document).on("shiny:inputchanged", function (event) {
  if (event.name === "bins") {
    event.value === 1
      ? $("#distPlot").css("visibility", "hidden")
      : $("#distPlot").css("visibility", "visible");
  }
});
```
````

We can use `jQuery` syntax as `shiny` depends on it.

Note: if you don't want to use JS and are open to an additional R package, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44790028/show-hide-entire-box-element-in-r-shiny) answer which explains how to do so using R's `shinyjs` package. I haven't tested this with a Quarto document that uses the `shiny` runtime.

Comment: @BenNutzer your new minimal example won't compile for me. If I  add `context = "server"` to the R code block it will, but it doesn't display anything.

Comment: Thanks again! Building on your answer I was able to [adapt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77555764/values-not-updating-after-hiding-showing-sections) the js code.